# How to connect to Google CloudSQL PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, go-gorm

I tried to connect to Google CloudSQL PostgresSQL using Gorm golang and seems like it is not working.

Here's the code

```
func InitDB() *gorm.DB {

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", os.Getenv("DB_HOST"), os.Getenv("DB_PORT"), os.Getenv("DB_USER"), os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"), os.Getenv("DB_NAME"))
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to connect to the Database")
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected to the Database")
    DB = db
    return DB
}
```

If im using the localhost config everything works fine. See my .env file for cloudSQL config

```
DB_HOST=trader-234509:us-central1:testv1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=username
DB_NAME=testv1
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Error is saying

> dial tcp: lookup trader-234509:us-central1:testv1: no such host
>       panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>       [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x164681d]

My local config (This one works fine)

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=username
DB_NAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the cloudsql instance's ip address as the `hostaddr` instead of `host`? As seen here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect

Comment: im using gorm http://doc.gorm.io/database.html#connecting-to-a-database hostaddr is not part of the library rule

Comment: In that case have you tried using the instance IP as the `host`?

Comment: If you are talking about public ip. Yeah I tried it and still error

Comment: And have you tried using only the instance name as the host? E.g. `host=testv1`?

Comment: Or try `"cloudsqlpostgres"` as the driverName to gorm.Open and import `_ "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/postgres"` like it's done here https://github.com/fanky5g/pgdb/blob/e40ce00693554118478bcfac3af9cbe8832715bc/postgres.go#L33

Comment: Thanks, but as for DB_HOST should I use Public IP or Instance connection name ?

Comment: ```The error failed to parse addr: "[trader-234509:us-central1:testv1]:user=username". It should conform to the regular expression "^\\[(.+)\\]:[0-9]+$```

Comment: Hey man @mkopriva thanks I used the instance connection and it works!

Comment: Appreciate your help and time to help me !

Answer (score 1):

Here's roughly how I connect from AppEngine:

```
import (
  _ "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/postgres"
  "fmt"
  "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
  "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func New() (*gorm.DB, error) {
  user := "theuser"
  password := "apassword"
  dbHost := "my-project:the-region:my-db-instance-name"
  databaseName := "mydbname"

  connString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable password=%s", dbHost, user, databaseName, password)
  
  return gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
    DriverName: "cloudsqlpostgres",
    DSN: connString,
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL doesn't support direct connection to instance name for 3rd party application yet, for details: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app

Based on my experience, there are 2 solutions:

1. As per above instruction, you can setup a Cloud Proxy following the steps and the connections flow would be:  Golang app -> Cloud Proxy -> Cloud SQL
   This approach is flexible and you're able to control the connection using firewall. 

   But you have to spend extra $$ to maintain the server and this cloud proxy instance, I've also heard that the cloud proxy may have some performance issues but I don't have exact evidence so far
2. Assign a Private IP to the Cloud SQL instance, refer to https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip, so that you application can access the DB directly using this IP.

   The trade-off is obvious that the app must be in the same network of the project, but this is a much more convenient approach, esp. all your applications are hosted in the same network

I didn't try out the public IP access approach as Cloud Proxy is just what I need if remote network connection is needed

In short, you need to deploy your code in a VM or other Google Managed service using option 2, or setup the cloud proxy to support your local debugging for option 1

Hope it helps